# Google Storage - Backup Bucket with Different Key For Each File

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I need to backup a bucket in which every file is encrypted with a different key to a different bucket on Google Storage.

I want to create a daily snapshot of the data so in a case where the data has been deleted I could easily recover it.

My Research:

1. Using `gsutil cp -r` - because every file has a different key it does not work
2. Using `Google Transfer | cloud` - does not work on such buckets from the same reason
3. List all the files in the bucket and fetch all the keys from the database and copy each file - this will probably be very expensive to do because i have a lot of files and i want to do it daily
4. Object versioning - Does not cover a case where the bucket has been completely deleted

Are there any other solutions for that problem?

Comment: Hi @Montoya please, consider accepting/upvoting my answer, in case it helped with your doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as you mentioned the only option indeed, would be to follow your number 3 choice. As you said and as clarified in this official documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/customer-supplied-keys#restrictions), download of encrypted data is a restricted feature, so you won't be able to download/snapshot the data, without fetching the keys and then copying the files.

Indeed, this will probably make a huge impact in your quota and pricing, since you will be performing multiple operations everyday, for multiple files, which will affect multiple aspects on the [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing). However, this seems to be the only available way right now. In addition to this, I would recommend you to raise a Feature Request in [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187243&template=0), so they can check about the possibility of implementing this in the future.

Let me know if the clarifed your doubts!